# Docker bundle install cache issues when updating gems

Tags: ruby, docker, npm, bundler, dockerfile

I use docker in both development and production and one thing which really bugs me is docker cache simplicity. I have ruby application which requires `bundle install` to install dependencies so I start with the following Dockerfile:

`ADD Gemfile Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install --path /root/bundle`

All dependencies are cached and it works great until I add a new gem. Even if gem I have added is just 0.5 MB it still takes 10-15 minutes to install all application gems from scratch. And then another 10 minutes to deploy it due to the size of dependencies folder ( about 300MB).

I have encountered exactly the same problem with node_modules and npm. I was wondering, did anyone found solution for this problem?

My research results so far:

- [Source to image](https://github.com/openshift/source-to-image) - caches arbitrary files across incremental builds. Unfortunately, due to the way it works it requires to push the whole 300MB to a registry even when gems are not changed. Faster build -> slower deploy even when gems are not updated.
- [Gemfile.tip](https://github.com/cpuguy83/docker-rails-dev-demo/blob/master/Dockerfile#L17) - split Gemfile into two different files and only add gems to one of them. Very specific solution to bundler and I am not convinced that it is gonna scale beyond adding 1-2 gems.
- [Harpoon](http://harpoon.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/recursive_containers.html) - would be a good fit if not the fact that they force ditching of Dockerfile and switch to they own format. Which means extra pain for all new devs in a team as this toolset requires time to learn separately from docker.
- Temporarily package cache. That is just an idea I had not sure is it possible. Somehow bring package manager cache ( not the dependencies folder ) to the machine before installing packages and then remove it. Based on my hack it significantly speedups package installation for both bundler and npm without bloating the machine with unnecessary cache files.

Comment: It should be possible to copy the gem directory out of the built image into a tar file. Then you could add a layer just before your ADD Gemfile Gemfile that restores that gem directory back into the image. At that point only the changes should need to be rebuilt. I'm experimenting with that technique now. If I get it to work I'll post an answer.

Comment: @ScottJacobsen any luck so far?

Comment: @jQwierdy - posted my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cache the gems to a tar file in the application tmp directory. Then I copy the gems into a layer using the `ADD` command before doing the bundle install. From my `Dockerfile.yml`:

```
WORKDIR /home/app

# restore the gem cache. This only runs when
# gemcache.tar.bz2 changes, so usually it takes
# no time
ADD tmp/gemcache.tar.bz2 /var/lib/gems/

COPY Gemfile /home/app/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /home/app/Gemfile.lock
RUN gem update --system && \
gem update bundler && \
bundle install --jobs 4 --retry 5
```

Be sure you are sending the gem cache to your docker machine. My gemcache is 118MB, but since I am building locally it copies fast. My `.dockerignore`:

```
tmp
!tmp/gemcache.tar.bz2
```

You need to cache the gems from a built image, but initially you may not have an image. Create an empty cache like so (I have this in a rake task):

```
task :clear_cache do
  sh "tar -jcf tmp/gemcache.tar.bz2 -T /dev/null"
end
```

After the image is built copy the gems to the gem cache. My image is tagged `app`. I create a docker container from the image, copy `/var/lib/gems/2.2.0` into my gemcache using the `docker cp` command, and then delete the container. Here's my rake task:

```
task :cache_gems do
  id = `docker create app`.strip
  begin
    sh "docker cp #{id}:/var/lib/gems/2.2.0/ - | bzip2 > tmp/gemcache.tar.bz2"
  ensure
    sh "docker rm -v #{id}"
  end
end
```

On the subsequent image build the gemcache is copied to a layer before the `bundle install` is called. This takes some time, but it is faster than a `bundle install` from scratch.

Builds after that are even faster because the docker has cached the `ADD tmp/gemcache.tar.bz2 /var/lib/gems/` layer. If there are any changes to `Gemfile.lock` only those changes are built.

There is no reason to rebuild the gem cache on each `Gemfile.lock` change. Once there are enough differences between the cache and the `Gemfile.lock` that a `bundle install` is slow you can rebuild the gem cache. When I do want to rebuild the gem cache it is a simple `rake cache_gems` command.

Comment: Interesting solution. Though my concern would be manual step of running cache gems at some undefined point in time.

Comment: Could do something like this in the dockerfile "bundle check || (bundle install && rake cache_gems)" would that have the expected behaviour?

Comment: It would make it so only when the bundle had changed, it would install and every time it installed it would cache the gems :-)

Comment: bundle check could speed it up a small amount, but bundle install is pretty fast when there is nothing to do.

Answer (score 3):

I found two possible solutions that use external data volume for gem storage: [one](https://medium.com/@fbzga/how-to-cache-bundle-install-with-docker-7bed453a5800) and [two](http://www.atlashealth.com/blog/2014/09/persistent-ruby-gems-docker-container/).

Briefly,

- you specify an image that is used to store gems only
- in your *app* images, in `docker-compose.yml` you specify the mount point for `BUNDLE_PATH` via `volumes_from`.
- when your app container starts up, it executes `bundle check || bundle install` and things are good to go.

This is one possible solution, however to me it feels like it goes slightly against the docker way. Specifically, `bundle install` to me sounds like it should be part of the build process and shouldn't be part of the runtime. Other things, that depend on the `bundle install` like `asset:precompile` are now a runtime task as well.

This is a vaiable solution but I'm looking forward to something a little more robust.

Answer (score 1):

The "copy local dependencies" approach (accepted answer) is a bad idea IMO. The whole point of dockerizing your environment is to have an isolated, reproducible environment.

Here's [how we are doing it](https://github.com/c-hive/guides/blob/2d3e41b73515a571dd78576e02d2fd15fe786d9e/docker/best-practices.md#use-separate-service-to-cache-dependencies-in-development-environment).

```
# .docker/docker-compose.dev.yml
version: '3.7'
services:

  web:
    build: .
    command: 'bash -c "wait-for-it cache:1337 && bin/rails server"'
    depends_on:
      - cache
    volumes:
      - cache:/bundle
    environment:
      BUNDLE_PATH: '/bundle'

  cache:
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: .docker/cache.Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - bundle:/bundle
    environment:
      BUNDLE_PATH: '/bundle'
    ports:
      - "1337:1337"

volumes:
  cache:
```

```
# .docker/cache.Dockerfile
FROM ruby:2.6.3
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y netcat-openbsd
COPY Gemfile* ./
COPY .docker/cache-entrypoint.sh ./
RUN chmod +x cache-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ./cache-entrypoint.sh
```

```sh
# .docker/cache-entrypoint.sh
#!/bin/bash

bundle check || bundle install
nc -l -k -p 1337
```

```
# web.dev.Dockerfile
FROM ruby:2.6.3
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y nodejs wait-for-it
WORKDIR ${GITHUB_WORKSPACE:-/app}
# Note: bundle install step removed
COPY . ./
```

This is similar to the concept explained by @EightyEight but it doesn't put `bundle install` into the main service's startup, instead, the update is managed by a different service. Either way, don't use this approach in production. Running services without their dependencies being installed in the build step will at the very least cause more downtime than necessary.

Comment: That's a very interesting approach indeed. Looking forward to try it next time

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem recently.
I'm working on a project with several dependencies with native extensions, which would make building a new docker image take around 15 minutes whenever something changed in the Gemfile.

I wasn't really into the idea of deferring the dependencies install to the run step with an external volume, so I did some more research and after some trial and error I managed to get the bundler cache working during the build process.

What I did was add a cache mount to my Dockerfile with the following code:

```
...
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock $app
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/bundler \
    BUNDLE_PATH=/bundler bundle install --jobs 3 --verbose && \
    cp -r /bundler/ruby/3.2.0/* /usr/local/bundle
...
```

(Note that the path may be different depending on the ruby version you are working with)

I imagine this may have not been a supported docker feature back when the other answers were submitted.